# Create the loop for multiple raster convert to vector polygon using the arcpy scripting tool

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, python-script-tool, loop, raster-conversion

This is my code which works only with the one raster image. But I need to create the tool that converts the multiple raster to vector in loop with arcpy.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace ='in_memory'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(input,output)
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_loop.asp

Comment: It looks like you have a Python Script Tool which let's your user input one raster and a name for your one output feature class.  How would you envisage your user interacting with your tool dialog if you introduced a loop?